# Why does PHP convert some angle brackets to html entities in PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer and have this line of code inside a for loop to add lines of an HTML table to the body of an email. (full pastebin of php is here: http://pastebin.com/iujp27hU)

```
$body .= "<tr><td style='". $rush_part_style . "'>" . $row[0]
     . "</td> <td align='center' style='" . $rush_part_style . "'>" . $quantity_to_order
     . "</td> <td>" . $row[2] . "</td></tr>";
```

The emails normally come out just fine but every once in a while, one of the angled brackets of the `td` tags is encoded to its HTML entity.

[image]

When I view the source in Outlook, here's what it looks like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">h3, p, table td {font-family:arial;}</style>
<table><tr><td><u>SD Part Number</u></td><td><u>Quantity</u></td><td><u>UOM</u>/td></tr>    
              - - some rows removed for brevity - -    
<tr><td style="">P1400642-00048-C</td><td align="center" style="">26</td><td>EA</td></tr>
<tr><td style="">P1400642-00046-C</td>&lt; td align='center' style=''&gt;20</td>    <td>EA</td></tr>

<tr><td style="">P1400642-00106-C</td><td align="center" style="">25</td><td>EA</td></tr>
<tr><td style="">P1400642-00036-C</td><td align="center" style="">67</td><td>EA</td></tr>
...
```

I don't get why it randomly encodes one of those `<` `>` to their character entities.
This problem has happened before but I can send 100+ emails without it happening. The part number has no bearing on whether it appears or not.

How can I troubleshoot this?

--Additional Info Edit--

Testing a very large order of 202 lines produces these formatting errors upon sending.
This is with no attributes at all, just pure HTML. PHPMailer mangles it upon `Send()`.

[image]

Comment: What if you open the email in another email client, does it happen there too?

Comment: @Dagon OP has already observed this, and said as much in the question title and below the code snippet.

Comment: Try sending the same email but without any variables in that line of generated html. See if it still occurs. `$body    .= "<tr><td style=''></td><td align='center' style=''></td> <td></td></tr>";`
You might narrow it down to what's in the variables that is messing it up. See if the issue remains or moves someplace else in the mail.

Comment: are you 100% sure that this html was created by the same php line of code you published? is there any chance that you have conditional html generating so this row of table comes from another if {} else {} branch?

Comment: On the topic of troubleshooting / debugging. If you encounter a possible PHP problem. Make sure it's PHP first. Try echoing out the plain html first then add in the variables. See when it breaks and by what. Also always turn on `error_reporting()` to see warnings etc.

Comment: Here is a pastebin of the full php mailer script: http://pastebin.com/iujp27hU  The error is not reproducible on command. I could run this again with the same input and it generates fine.

Comment: @sjagr  It shows similiar in GMail webmail and it is also messed up on my Galaxy S4 built-in email client. On the phone the offending td tag is shown above the message.

Comment: @S.Mason Cool, just wanted to verify reproduciblity.

Comment: Try removing the floating space between your `<` and `td`, ie. `< td` -> `<td`

Comment: Even stranger is the `&gt;20`. There's no `>` in your original PHP/html, so why would a closing bracket be placed BEFORE the style value?

Answer (score 1):

Try outputting newline characters `\r\n` at the end of your table rows

```
$body    .= "<tr><td style='". $rush_part_style . "'>" . $row[0] . "</td> <td align='center' style='" . $rush_part_style . "'>" . $quantity_to_order . "</td> <td>" . $row[2] . "</td></tr>\r\n";
```

I had a similar issue, and on inspecting the source of the html email, it appeared that newline characters were somewhat arbitrarily inserted.  Adding newline after closing `</tr>` was the fix for me.

Answer (score 0):

The output has `&lt; td` while your PHP has `<td`. That's very odd, because the output suddenly has a space out of nothing.

To troubleshoot you could output `$body` and `$order_mail->Body` to the screen or a file when running the script. See at what point the escaped HTML is introduced. If that doesn't give you more information, try without PHP variables, and just fill in some random stuff yourself.

Other ideas:

- PHPMailer may have a problem with the attribute being empty (`style=''`) - you could try rewriting your code so that empty attributes are left out (or so that attributes are never empty by adding some dummy text, e.g., for style: `text-align:left;`).
- Try double quotes (`"` instead of `'`) in the HTML, PHPMailer may have a problem with that.

In general on debugging: split up your code and output debugging info as much as possible to determine where exactly you have the problem. Is it in building the HTML, or is it done by PHPMailer at the moment you load it into `$order_mail->Body`? Or does it happen when you call `Send()` (in that case you can't see it happening with PHP)?

Comment: Interestingly, I outputted $order_mail->Body and $body to the screen and cannot reproduce the character encoding issue, the table is created fine. But when that Body gets put through the PHPMailer Send() function, it sometimes gets changed and it randomly changes some of the < >. I can reproduce the error but it's not at the same character each time, sometimes one line will have it sometimes another line, and sometimes none! Perhaps whatever server is processing it is getting overwhelmed somehow.

Comment: @S.Mason Did you try my other suggestions (no empty HTML attributes and double quotes instead of single quotes) as well? I can try to find some time to look into the Send() function and will report back.

Comment: I added a screenshot of select parts of a test email. I'm using I'm using PHPMailer 5.1 (can't upgrade as 5.2 doesn't work for some reason) I think the problem is with PHPMailer inserting a space in certain spots. Like the input buffer is full and when it starts another input buffer, it adds a space before the input. Or wondering if problem lies with the PHPMailer use of the set_magic_quotes_runtime() function, something there not working right.

Comment: @S.Mason I'd advise you to do the same trick as before (outputting the body along the way), but now also in the PHPMailer class. Make a backup of the current class, then put `var_dump(the-body)` on strategic places in the Send() function and the functions it calls, to find exactly where it goes wrong.

Comment: If you don't have these problems when you echo / dump the html in PHP, then i'd very much like to see your code for sending mails.

Comment: @EJTH I don't use PHPMailer, I just gave some general debugging help.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will help your issue but worth a go, you can avoid concatenating PHP to HTML by putting your variable in braces `{$rush_part_style}` and just putting that in your HTML. This saves you from closing and reopening html.

Comment: BTW there's no need for braces to avoid concatenation here.  "<td id='$rush_id'>" or "<td id=\"$rush_id\">" will echo the variable because  double quotes are used. Braces are useful for array members or object properties, though, as in "<td id=\"{$rush_part->id}\">"